# Push Notification different Sounds iOS XCode

Tags: ios, push-notification

Hello fellow mobile developers,

I'm currently working on a Swift project for an iOS app that involves receiving notifications. The app is designed to play different sounds based on a specific parameter when a notification arrives. However, I'm encountering an issue that needs addressing:

When the app is in the foreground, everything works as expected, and the correct sound is played based on the associated notification type. However, when the app is in the background, it consistently plays the same sound, regardless of the notification type.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the app plays the appropriate sound even when running in the background.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I use XCode 14.3.1 and iphone 15.7.2

I add the code below:

```
    //
//  PushNotificationHandler.swift
//  Copyright © 2020 DuckMa Srl. All rights reserved.
//

import AVFoundation
import FirebaseMessaging
import Logging
import MediaPlayer
import UIKit

final class PushNotificationHandler: NSObject {
    let window: UIWindow
    fileprivate var timer: Timer?
    fileprivate var vibrationTimer: Timer?
    private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer
    private var audioPlayerFS: AVAudioPlayer
    private var audioPlayerDAE: AVAudioPlayer
    private var audioPlayerRC: AVAudioPlayer
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
    let updateFcmToken: (String) -> Void
    let didReceiveAlarm: (IncomingAlarm) -> Void
    let messaging: Messaging

    init(
        window: UIWindow,
        messaging: Messaging = Messaging.messaging(),
        updateFcmToken: @escaping (String) -> Void,
        didReceiveAlarm: @escaping (IncomingAlarm) -> Void
    ) {
        self.window = window
        self.messaging = messaging
        self.updateFcmToken = updateFcmToken
        self.didReceiveAlarm = didReceiveAlarm

        guard
            let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "allarme", ofType: "mp3"),
            let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound))
        else { preconditionFailure("Could not initialize player") }
        audioPlayer = player

        guard
            let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "alarm FARMACO", ofType: "wav"),
            let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound))
        else { preconditionFailure("Could not initialize player") }
        audioPlayerFS = player

        guard
            let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "alarm DAE", ofType: "wav"),
            let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound))
        else { preconditionFailure("Could not initialize player") }
        audioPlayerDAE = player

        guard
            let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "alarm COVID", ofType: "wav"),
            let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound))
        else { preconditionFailure("Could not initialize player") }
        audioPlayerRC = player

        super.init()

        self.messaging.delegate = self
    }

    deinit {
        Logger.App.info("Logger: deinit `PushNotificationHandler`")
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        vibrationTimer?.invalidate()
        if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            audioPlayer.stop()
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        }
        if audioPlayerFS.isPlaying {
            audioPlayerFS.stop()
            audioPlayerFS.prepareToPlay()
        }
        if audioPlayerRC.isPlaying {
            audioPlayerRC.stop()
            audioPlayerRC.prepareToPlay()
        }
        if audioPlayerDAE.isPlaying {
            audioPlayerDAE.stop()
            audioPlayerDAE.prepareToPlay()
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(
                withIdentifiers: [Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "com.duckma.SOSScuole"]
            )
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(
                withIdentifiers: [Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "com.duckma.SOSScuole"]
            )
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - MessagingDelegate

extension PushNotificationHandler: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        guard let fcmToken = fcmToken else { return }
        Logger.App.info("Logger: fcmToken \(fcmToken)")
        updateFcmToken(fcmToken)
    }
}

// MARK: - Alarm notification

extension PushNotificationHandler {
    func startWork(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], publishNotification: Bool = true) {
        for key in userInfo.keys {
            print("\(key) : \(userInfo[key]!)")
        }
        Logger.App.info("Logger: Start publishing notification")
        stopTimer()
        guard
            let alarmAction = (userInfo["action"] as? String).flatMap(
                IncomingAlarm.Action.init(rawValue:)
            ),
            let alarmId = userInfo["alarm_id"] as? String
        else { return }
        let title = (userInfo["title"] as? String) ?? ""
        let message = (userInfo["body"] as? String) ?? ""
        let alarmDuration = (userInfo["alarm_timeout"] as? Int) ?? 120
        let alarmType = (userInfo["type"] as? String) ?? ""
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if publishNotification {
                self.publishNotification(title: title, message: message, type: alarmType)
            }
            let alarm = IncomingAlarm(id: alarmId, duration: alarmDuration, action: alarmAction, type: alarmType)
            self.didReceiveAlarm(alarm)
            if alarm.action == .stop {
                self.stopTimer()
                return
            }

            if publishNotification {
                self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 9, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
                    Logger.App.info("Logger: rescheduling at \(Date())")
                    self?.publishNotification(title: title, message: message, type: alarmType)
                }
                self.vibrationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.5, repeats: true) { _ in
                    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func publishNotification(title: String, message: String, type: String) {
        Logger.App.info("Logger: Publishing notification")

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(
                .playAndRecord, options: [.duckOthers, .defaultToSpeaker]
            )
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

            volumeView.setVolume(1) {
                if self.volumeView.superview == nil {
                    self.window.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(self.volumeView)
                }

                self.audioPlayerRC.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: 0.5)
                self.audioPlayerDAE.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: 0.5)
                self.audioPlayerFS.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: 0.5)
                self.audioPlayer.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: 0.5)
                switch type {
                case "FS":
                    self.audioPlayerFS.play()
                case "DAE":
                    self.audioPlayerDAE.play()
                case "RC":
                    self.audioPlayerRC.play()
                default:
                    self.audioPlayer.play()
                }
            }
        } catch {
            Logger.App.info("Logger: Audio Session error: \(error)")
        }

        let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        notification.title = title
        notification.body = message

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(
            identifier: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "com.duckma.SOSScuole",
            content: notification,
            trigger: trigger
        )
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            guard error == nil else { return }
        }
    }
}

extension PushNotificationHandler: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        // MARK: notifica ricevuta quando app in foreground
        let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
        if state == .background || state == .inactive {
            // background
            completionHandler([.badge, .banner, .list, .sound])
        } else if state == .active {
            // foreground
            let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
            let alarm_id =
                (userInfo["alarm_id"] as? String) ?? (userInfo["gcm.notification.alarm_id"] as? String)
            let action = (userInfo["action"] as? String)?.uppercased() ?? "START"
            if let alarmId = alarm_id {
                startWork(
                    userInfo: [
                        "action": action,
                        "alarm_id": alarmId,
                        "title": notification.request.content.title,
                        "body": notification.request.content.body,
                        "type": notification.request.content.userInfo["type"] as! String,
                    ],
                    publishNotification: true
                )
            }
        }
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // MARK: notifica ricevuta quando app in background
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        let alarm_id =
            (userInfo["alarm_id"] as? String) ?? (userInfo["gcm.notification.alarm_id"] as? String)
        let action = (userInfo["action"] as? String)?.uppercased() ?? "START"
        if let alarmId = alarm_id {
            startWork(
                userInfo: [
                    "action": action,
                    "alarm_id": alarmId,
                    "title": response.notification.request.content.title,
                    "body": response.notification.request.content.body,
                ],
                publishNotification: false
            )
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
}

extension MPVolumeView {
    func setVolume(_ volume: Float, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let slider = subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.01) {
            slider?.value = volume
            completion()
        }
    }
}

// http://andrewmarinov.com/building-an-alarm-app-on-ios/
private extension MPVolumeView {
    var volumeSlider: UISlider? {
        showsRouteButton = false
        showsVolumeSlider = false
        isHidden = true
        let slider = subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider
        slider?.isContinuous = false
        return slider
    }
}
```